# Replace html element out of JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am working with a package that sends a string (html content) to my webhook that I need to replace with other text:

```
const x = `
<div dir="ltr">fifi<div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Screen Shot 2022-10-07 at 4.36.08 PM.png" width="335" height="483"><br></div>
</div>
`
```

The `img` is a blob file and is actually much longer, just shortened it for this. I figure the easiest way to find the part of the string is by the `alt` tag as I will have that string available to me. I am unsure how to proceed to have the entirety of `<img .....>` replaced with variable `y`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace `<img ...>` by regex

```js
const x = `
<div dir="ltr">fifi<div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Screen Shot 2022-10-07 at 4.36.08 PM.png" width="335" height="483"><br></div>
</div>
`

const regex = /<img[^>]*>/g

const y = "Your variable"

const output = x.replaceAll(regex, y)

//if you want to replace for the first occurrence only
//you can use `replace` instead
//const output = x.replace(regex, y)

console.log(output)
```